# как сохранить имена папок в список строк

Tags: c#, list

имеется код. его задача-сохранить имена папок из directory в список строк, НО если допустим в этой директории куча папок, как мне сделать так, чтобы в список строк добавлялись имена только нужных мне папок?

По пути directory допустим, есть папки "Du", "rre", "ll". этот код добавит все имена этих папок в список строк, как мне сделать так, чтобы добавилось только то название папки, которое необходимо - "rre"

```
List<string> allFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory).Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(d).Name).ToList();
```

Comment: а как вы отличаете необходимые папки от не необходимых?

Comment: `List<string> myFolders = new List<string> { "rre" }; List<string> allFolders = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(directory).Select(d => new DirectoryInfo(d).Name).Where(n => myFolders.Contains(n)).ToList();`

Comment: благодарю! все работает